# sed and rev shell command into Python script

Tags: python, bash, shell, sh

There is a shell command, I am trying to convert the logic into python. But I don't know what to do, I need some help with that.

shell command is this :

```
cd ../../../tests/src/main/test
ls
find . -name '*.vrlp' | while read FILENAME
do
    TEST_CASE=`echo $FILENAME | sed s/"\.\/"//g | sed s/"\.vrlp"//g | rev | cut -f1 -d"/" | rev`
    CLASS=`echo $FILENAME | sed s/"\.\/"//g | sed s/"\/$TEST_CASE"//g | sed s/"\.vrlp"//g`
```

The logic is inside a directory, filter all exists file by using find . -name '*.vrlp', includes all sub-folders

Then retrieve the data into parameters.

```
TEST_CASE=`echo $FILENAME | sed s/"\.\/"//g | sed s/"\.vrlp"//g | rev | cut -f1 -d"/" | rev`
    CLASS=`echo $FILENAME | sed s/"\.\/"//g | sed s/"\/$TEST_CASE"//g | sed s/"\.vrlp"//g`
```

I tried something like follows, but I don't know the sed command exactly doing and how to convert it into python script. for example

For retrieve the data send to parameter CLASS and TESTCASE , I did the cut (

```
cut -f1 -d"/"
```

) but I don't know how to do the sed and rev to retrieve the value for TEST_CASE and CLASS

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(../../../tests/src/main/test):
    for file in files:
        file_name = os.path.basename(file)
        file = os.path.splitext(file_name)
        if '.vrlp' in file:
            FILENAME = file[0] + file[1]
                TEST_CASE = FILENAME.split("/")[0] // how to apply sed and rev here?
                CLASS = FILENAME // how to apply sed here?
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Yours is very similar to a number of recent questions about how to replace simple Bash code with Python. Stack Overflow requires a _single_ and _specific_ question; if you need to reverse a string in Python, search for that. Etcetera. Moreover, the shell scripts you have are atrociously bad, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TEST_CASE=` command is taking the value of FILENAME, removing the ./ prefix and the .vrlp suffix, reversing the order of characters, extracting the first field based on / as delimiter, and then reversing the order of characters again.

Then, the `CLASS=` command is taking the value of FILENAME, removing the ./ prefix, removing the /$TEST_CASE suffix, and removing the .vrlp suffix.

In python:

```
import os

os.chdir("../../../tests/src/main/test")
print(os.listdir())

for FILENAME in os.popen("find . -name '*.vrlp'"):
    FILENAME = FILENAME.strip()
    TEST_CASE = os.path.basename(FILENAME).replace(".vrlp", "")
    CLASS = os.path.dirname(FILENAME).replace("./", "").replace("/{}".format(TEST_CASE), "").replace(".vrlp", "")
```